# SQL Query - Sum Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to calculate a value inside a view, from 2 rows on a table.
SQL Server.

The table has these columns

```
----------------------------------------------
|RefId | Quantity | TransferFrom | TransferTo |
----------------------------------------------
|5601  | 100      | 5580         | null       |
-----------------------------------------------
|5850  | 200      | null         | 5601       |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I would like to add the quantity of the current row, and the quantity of another row if the other row's TransferTo col equals the current row's RefId.

In the view I have:

```
MyAmount = [Quantity] + (SELECT [Quantity] 
                         FROM MyTable  
                         WHERE [TransferTo] = [RefId])
```

However, this is returning `NULL`.

Would I better be using variables or a `CAST` function?

Thanks in advance for any input

Comment: [Quantity] or the SELECT returns a NULL value so the sum yields NULL. You can check both values with ISNULL() and set to 0 of each. And think what happens if the SELECT returns more than 1 value. The query will raise an error

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the subquery could be returning `NULL`.  This is a case where `ISNUL()` is preferable over `COALESCE()`:

```
MyAmount = ([Quantity] +
            ISNULL((SELECT t2.[Quantity] FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t2.[TransferTo] = t.[RefId]), 0)
           )
```

(This assumes that the table alias from the outer query is `t`.)

`ISNULL()` is preferable because `COALESCE()` might evaluate the subquery twice, which is unnecessary overhead.  (Otherwise, I prefer `COALESCE()` because it is the ANSI standard function.)

Note:  If you are using correlated subqueries, you should *always* qualify all your column names.

Answer (score 0):

You Will Get the Value as `NULL` while adding 2 values if either of the value is `NULL`. So Use the ISNULL() on both sides to avoid the `NULL`.

```
MyAmount = ISNULL([Quantity],0.00) + ISNULL((SELECT [Quantity] 
                         FROM MyTable  
                         WHERE [TransferTo] = [RefId]),0.00)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want get this result?

```
 ;WITH MyTable(RefId,Quantity,TransferFrom,TransferTo) AS(
      SELECT 5601,100,5580,null UNION ALL 
      SELECT 5850 ,200,null , 5601
)
SELECT x.*,MyAmount = x.[Quantity]+ISNULL( y.[Quantity] ,0)

FROM MyTable x
LEFT JOIN MyTable  AS y ON x.TransferTo=y.RefId
```

```
RefId   Quantity    TransferFrom    TransferTo  MyAmount
5601    100 5580    NULL    100
5850    200 NULL    5601    300
```